# How to dynamically attribute different counters to several elements

Tags: javascript

I have 16 triangles that rotate individually 90 degrees on clicking button1. 
because I have several buttons that perform different tasks I push all the event listeners into an array so they could be removed and added.

now the function that rotates the triangles works. but each triangle keeps picking up on the counter of the previous ones, always spinning too much on the first click and then spins the 90 degrees.

I'm thinking I need an individual counter for each triangle but as the code is setup I'm a bit lost and I don't know what is the best approach.

here's fiddle with only the relevant code
http://jsfiddle.net/antonimoferraz/xcd5wz2e/16

```
    document.getElementById('reflective').addEventListener('click',reflective);
document.getElementById('thinking').addEventListener('click',thinking);

let elementos = document.querySelectorAll('div.elements');
    let enhancedElements = [];
    let enhancedElementsclick = [];
    let degree = 90;
    let initial = 0;

// give to each element a separate event handler so it's easy to add and remove when I press different buttons

elementos.forEach(element => {
  enhancedElements.push({
    element,
    mouseenterHandler(){mouseenterHandler(element)},
  })

})

elementos.forEach(element => {

  enhancedElementsclick.push({
    element,
    clickHandler(){clickHandler(element)},
  })

})


//button n1
//removes event listeners from thinking() and adds its own events
function reflective(){

      enhancedElements.forEach(ee => {
        ee.element.removeEventListener('mouseenter', ee.mouseenterHandler)
      })
      enhancedElementsclick.forEach(ee => {
        ee.element.addEventListener('click', ee.clickHandler)
        console.log(ee.counterfunction);

      })
}
//button n2
//removes event listeners from reflective() and adds its own events
function thinking(){

      enhancedElementsclick.forEach(ee => {
        ee.element.removeEventListener('click', ee.clickHandler)
      })
      enhancedElements.forEach(ee => {
        ee.element.addEventListener('mouseenter', ee.mouseenterHandler)

})

}

//what happens on click
function clickHandler(elementt) {

       initial += degree;
       elementt.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+initial+'deg)';
       elementt.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+initial+'deg)';
       elementt.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+initial+'deg)';
       elementt.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+initial+'deg)';
       elementt.style.transform       = 'rotate('+initial+'deg)';
}

function mouseenterHandler(elementt){
// does something else
}
```

appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Just put the initial value into element itself:

```
elementos.forEach(element => {
  element.initial = 0; // this line
  enhancedElementsclick.push({
    element,
    clickHandler(){clickHandler(element)},
  })
})
```

And then inside your handler, you can use `elementt.initial`:

```
function clickHandler(elementt) {
   elementt.initial += degree;
   elementt.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+elementt.initial+'deg)';
   elementt.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+elementt.initial+'deg)';
   elementt.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+elementt.initial+'deg)';
   elementt.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+elementt.initial+'deg)';
   elementt.style.transform       = 'rotate('+elementt.initial+'deg)';
}
```

Enjoy :)

**Side Note:**  you do not need to loop everytime you use another array, instead merge them in a single place:

```
elementos.forEach(element => {

  enhancedElements.push({/*your_data*/})

  enhancedElementsclick.push({/*your_data*/})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra parameter to objects in `enhancedElements` that keeps track of object rotation

```
  enhancedElements.push({
    element,
    rotation: 0,
    mouseenterHandler(){mouseenterHandler(element)},
  })
```

```
function clickHandler(elementt) {
       const el = enhancedElements.find(e => e.element == elementt)
       el.rotation += degree;
       elementt.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+el.rotation+'deg)';
       elementt.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+el.rotation+'deg)';
       elementt.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+el.rotation+'deg)';
       elementt.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+el.rotation+'deg)';
       elementt.style.transform       = 'rotate('+el.rotation+'deg)';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you need a individul counter.

```
      //create counters  
      var counters=[15];
      for (var i=0;i<16;i++){
      counters[i]=0;
      }
      //create id storage  
      var elements=[15];
      for (var i=0;i<16;i++){
      elements[i]="element"+"_"+i;
      }
```

now you can have inside your event handler a function whih will determine the numer of the triangle. I would rename the IDS to element_id cause now you just need a simple split to get the id of the triangle by the event.target.id.

And by this you can now look in the arrays which counter to be used or which id or.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get current rotation of a particular element from `elementt.style.transform` this will hold the value `"rotate(90deg)"`. From this you can derive the current rotation and then add the rotation value i.e 90.

This way you can relatively rotate each triangle instead of tracking all their status.